# How to set variable from one component to another?

Tags: angular

I two Angular `components`, one is a `navbar` that is up on every page, by default that `navbar` has a cart that is hidden but while some conditions are true i have to show that cart.

The navbar is called in `app.component` as is up in each page:

```
<app-top-bar></app-top-bar> // navbar component
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Now i have another `component` that is called `NegozioComponent` and is routed as a page, in that component i get the condition which says if the cart of navbar has to be visible or not.

NegozioComponent.ts looks like this

```
export class NegozioComponent implements OnInit {

  profilo: Profilo;
  idNegozio: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private profiloService: ProfiloService) {

    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.idNegozio = params.negozio;
  });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.profiloService.profilo(this.idNegozio).subscribe((profilo: Profilo) => {
      this.profilo = profilo;
      if(profilo.moduli) {
         // SET CART TO TRUE
       }
    });
  }

}
```

And inside it's ngOnInit `if(profilo.moduli)` i have to set the `carrello` variable from `TopBarComponent` to true

TopBarComponent.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-top-bar',
      templateUrl: './top-bar.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./top-bar.component.scss']
    })
    export class TopBarComponent implements OnInit {
      carrello = false;
    
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a Service, which can transfer this piece of info between the two components.

Your service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CartService {
  public cartIsEnabled = false;

  constructor() { }

}
```

Your component's ts, where the cart's status is set:

```js
this.cartService.cartIsEnabled = true;
```

Your cart-component's html:

```js
<cart *ngIf="cartService.cartIsEnabled"></cart>
```

If the change isn't detected and the cart doesn't show up, you can switch the cartIsEnabled variable to a [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject).